# Parsing json like structure with pyparsing

Tags: python, json, parsing, pyparsing

i try to parse following structure using pyparsing:

```
{
    firewall {
        group {
            address-group {
                address 1.2.3.4
            }
            address-group {
                address 5.6.7.4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

code:

```
from pyparsing import *

LBRACE, RBRACE = map(Suppress, "{}")

prop = Word(printables, excludeChars="{}\"")
numberValue = pyparsing_common.number()

configObject = Forward()
value = Forward()
value << (prop | numberValue | Group(configObject))
memberDef = Group(prop + value)
configMembers = delimitedList(memberDef)
configObject << Dict(LBRACE + Optional(configMembers) + RBRACE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testdata = """
    {
        firewall {
            group {
                address-group {
                    address 1.2.3.4
                }
                address-group {
                    address 1.2.3.4
                }
            }
        }
    }
    """


results = configObject.parseString(testdata)  

print(results.firewall.group)
```

It throws

> pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "}" (at char 15), (line:3, col:9)

If i have only a single `address-group` it is working:

```
{
    firewall {
        group {
            address-group {
                address 1.2.3.4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
{
    firewall {
        group {
            address-group {
                address 1.2.3.4
            }
            address-group {
                address 5.6.7.4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is solved using `configMembers = OneOrMore(memberDef)` instead of `configMembers = delimitedList(memberDef)`
I need to parse this also (note the `name` after `adress-group`:

```
{
    firewall {
        group {
            address-group name1 {
                address 1.2.3.4
            }
            address-group name2 {
                address 5.6.7.4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @BoswellGathu was on the right track. Adding a comma works around the bug in your parser where you use `delimitedList` when you have multiple entries in an object. `delimitedList` requires a non-whitespace delimiter between entries, the default being comma. If you just want to have multiple values with no delimiters, use `OneOrMore` or `ZeroOrMore`. (The next problem you will have is that you have duplicate keys, so only one will show up in your Dict.)

Comment: @PaulMcG its working using `OneOrMore` but as you mentioned it is a problem with the dublicated keys.

I also could export the config with names after each  `address-group` like `address-group name {...` but i dont know how to parse this. (New to parsing)

Comment: How about: `address-group { name1 1.2.3.4 name2 5.6.7.8 }`? I'm fairly sure that will parse with your current parser.

Comment: this isnt possible. only `address-group` can contain an `name` after it. so only `address-group name { address 1.2.3.4}` can be possible

Comment: The simplest change would be to modify `memberDef` to `memberDef = Group(Optional(Suppress('address-group')) + prop + value)`. You also have a bug in `value`, since it matches `prop`, `numberValue`, then the object group. The definition of `prop` is so broad that it will mask any string that would match the numeric expression, and since '|' takes the *first* match, `prop` will always win. Easily fixed by changing to `value <<= (numberValue | prop | Group(configObject))`.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a comma between the two address groups and everything works

```
{
firewall {
    group {
        address-group {
            address 1.2.3.4
        },
        address-group {
            address 5.6.7.4
        }
    }
}
}
```

The code therefore is

```
from pyparsing import *

LBRACE, RBRACE = map(Suppress, "{}")

prop = Word(printables, excludeChars="{}\"")
numberValue = pyparsing_common.number()

configObject = Forward()
value = Forward()
value << (prop | numberValue | Group(configObject))
memberDef = Group(prop + value)
configMembers = delimitedList(memberDef)
configObject << Dict(LBRACE + Optional(configMembers) + RBRACE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testdata = """
    {
        firewall {
            group {
                address-group {
                    address 1.2.3.4
                },
                address-group {
                    address 5.6.7.4
                }
            }
        }
    }
    """


results = configObject.parseString(testdata)

print(results.firewall.group)
```

and the output is

```
[['address-group', [['address', '1.2.3.4']]], ['address-group', [['address', 
'5.6.7.4']]]]
```

Comment: If the OP could change the format of the input, they would have just used JSON in the first place instead of something that needed a custom parser.

Comment: @jwodder this. It is NOT a json :)